# Bluetooth Low Energy Stack Overflow on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++builder

I wanted to write a program that is receiving data every 10ms over Bluetooth Low Energy.

I get a lot of things to work, but I always have one problem and can´t find the source.
Here is the basis of my Code written in C++Builder 10 on Windows 10.

```
> //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)

#define Characteristic_UUID "{6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e}"
#define Service_UUID        "{6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e}"
#pragma resource "*.dfm"



TForm1 *Form1;
TBluetoothLEDevice* device;
TBluetoothGattCharacteristicList* characteristic ;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
     BluetoothLE1->DiscoverDevices(100);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BluetoothLE1EndDiscoverDevices(TObject * const Sender, TBluetoothLEDeviceList * const ADeviceList)

{
             device = ADeviceList->First();

    BluetoothLE1->DiscoverServices(device);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BluetoothLE1ServicesDiscovered(TObject * const Sender, TBluetoothGattServiceList * const AServiceList)

{

           GUID AGuid;
    CLSIDFromString(TEXT(Service_UUID), &AGuid);
    TBluetoothGattService* service = BluetoothLE1->GetService(device,AGuid);
    //TBluetoothGattServiceList* abcd = BluetoothLE1->GetServices(device);


    CLSIDFromString(TEXT(Characteristic_UUID), &AGuid);
    characteristic = BluetoothLE1->GetCharacteristics(service);
    while(characteristic->First()->UUID != AGuid)
    {
           characteristic->Delete(0);

    }
    if(characteristic->First()!= NULL);
        BluetoothLE1->SubscribeToCharacteristic(device,characteristic->First());
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BluetoothLE1CharacteristicRead(TObject * const Sender, TBluetoothGattCharacteristic * const ACharacteristic,
          TBluetoothGattStatus AGattStatus)

{
    static long i;

    Label1->Caption = i;
    i++;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After exactly 86303 Notifys (calling BluetoothLE1CharacteristicRead) I get a Stack Overflow. So there must be something wrong.
At the beginning i wrote the program in Visual Studio in C++ with the Windows Drivers Functions, but same thing.

Comment: Write "stack overflow" to make difference from StackOverflow. The site is other thing :)

Comment: Have you checked the actual stack? It's usually a giveaway why the stack overflows. Typically you have a pattern `ABCABCABCABCAB` on it, some of which might not be your functions. A common cause is calling library functions from a callback so that the library calls your callback again ...

Comment: Ok i noticce now  nearly the whole stack is full of these 12Bytes 0x014F3200  -> .O2.
0x005FFF64 -> ._ÿd
0x00000000 -> ....
But how can i find out what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
It is a bug in the Win32 Bluetooth APIs.
With Windows Update KB3156421 every program crashes after one notification and Mircosoft gives a workaround. [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e30e43cf-4cda-40ab-9075-0e1babeaf23f/program-crashed-after-recived-bluetooth-le-notification?forum=wdk)

That workaround fixes my problem above too.